# ValueError when doing df.groupby('col1').col2.rank() with Pandas in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I received a ValueError when doing a groupby rank.

How do I properly calculate the grouped ranking?

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=[1,2,3], col2=[4,5,6])), 
                pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=[1,2,3], col2=[7,8,9]))])
df.groupby('col1').col2.rank()
```

With ValueError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'col1' is not defined
df.groupby('col1').col2.rank()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 35, in rank
  File "/Users/stephenpettinato/.virtualenvs/newt-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 592, in wrapper
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is one of the same index value for different rows of the input dataframe.

```
df.index
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Resetting the index will work to alleviate this error.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=[1, 2, 3], col2=[4, 5, 6])),
                pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=[1, 2, 3], col2=[7, 8, 9]))])
df.reset_index().groupby('col1').col2.rank()
```